# C++ convert unicode CString or wchar_t to LPBYTE

Tags: c++, mfc

I know it's simple question, but I have tried so many approaches, in all of them I lose data, text data, not those trailing 0's after each byte.

I converted `CString` to `wchar_t` using `GetBuffer(0)`, still no luck. I can't get a proper `LPBYTE`.

At end I need it to be `const LPBYTE`, but I think with a simple casting of `LPBYTE` I can get `const LPBYTE`.

So could you help me to convert `CString` or `wchar_t` to `LPBYTE` array?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try the CT2CA macro ?

Comment: Is it a UNIDOCDE or an ANSI project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "see" the content of a `CString` as a simple "raw" sequence (array) of `BYTE`'s, you can use `CString::GetString()` method to get the pointer to the first `CString` character, and then cast to `const BYTE*`:

```
CString str;
....
const BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(str.GetString());
```

If you want to "see" a single `wchar_t` as a sequence of `BYTE`'s, you can take its address and again cast to `const BYTE*`:

```
wchar_t wch;
....
const BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(&wch);
```

But if you want to convert from Unicode UTF-16 to another encoding like UTF-8, you may want to use some [conversion helpers like `CW2A`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
CString strUtf16; // Assume UNICODE builds (the default since VS2005)
....
// Convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8
CW2A strUtf8( strUtf16, CP_UTF8 );

// Convert (cast) to const BYTE*
const BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>( static_cast<const char*>(strUtf8) );
```

Comment: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const LPBYTE *' to 'const LPBYTE', I need const LPBYTE

Comment: `LPBYTE` can be confusing especially if you are a beginner; however, it just means `BYTE*`. Note that for clarity reasons I used `BYTE` in my code, with _explicit_ pointers (i.e. `const BYTE*`, not `const LPBYTE*`).

Comment: tried it with a casting, again I'm losing data, about half of data received

Comment: But do you want to convert say from Unicode UTF-16 to Unicode UTF-8? What do you precisely want to achieve? Please clarify your goals.

Comment: It's an MFC application, I have a CString which contains about 200 chars (probably as it's unicode proj and CString is unicode it will be 400, don't know). Then I have an API which accepts const LPBYTE to send. I tried different methods (including now your method), I receive half of bytes, I receive unicode data like A\0B\0C\0D\0 etc. but half of data, I lose other remaining part.

Comment: Maybe you make a mistake in passing the size parameter (assuming there is one...). If the size is expressed in _bytes_, then compute it as `stringLengthInWChars * sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: in a Unicode MFC project, what is the default type of CString? UTF16 or 8?

Comment: In a Unicode MFC project, the default type of `CString` is UTF-16 (i.e. `CString` is `CStringW`).

Comment: What is strUtf8 in your last example?

Comment: `strUtf8` is an instance of `CW2A`, which is an helper class that can be used to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 (using `CP_UTF8` as second parameter).

Comment: Thanks, answer was: CW2A ntest( TotalBuf, CP_UTF8 );
 const BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>( static_cast<char*>(ntest) ); sockHandle.Write((const LPBYTE)pb);